# Moving Excel Data To SQL Server - Can This Be More Efficient C#

Tags: c#, datatable

This is going to be a rather long post, since I want to explain why I implemented certain styles of coding. The main goal is to see if I can make this program run faster with help from you guys!!

### Overview

Starting off, I have 23 different Excel Sheets that sit in a file. Some sheets are bigger than others but I have to import ALL of the data within each of them. Each of the column header names in these Excel Sheets have been created as classes in C# - there are 23 of these classes. In order to grab the data, there is a front-end that accepts an Excel file and then `ExcelDataReader` is used to read the tables in a way that they can become `DataTable` objects.

There is a general style that importing each Excel Sheet follows. I will use my vCPU class as an example First, the program cleans up the `DataTable` object that is being looked at by removing unnecessary rows. Then a `List<vCPUs>` object is made. Each row in the vCPU Excel Sheet makes up one `vCPU` object, so there is a `foreach` loop that goes through each `DataRow` in the `vCPU_Table`. That looks something like this:

```
public class vCPU
    {
        public static int Insert(DataTable vCPU_Table, int assessment_id, int objectCount)
        {
            //Cleans up the Data Table that is being accessed by removing unneccesary rows
            for (int i = vCPU_Table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (vCPU_Table.Rows[i][0].ToString() == String.Empty)
                {
                    vCPU_Table.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            List<RvtoolsVCpu> vCPUs = new List<RvtoolsVCpu>();
            using (var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in vCPU_Table.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["VM"].ToString() == "") //In case too many rows are selected, the name is always filled for corresponding data
                    {
                        context.RvtoolsVCpu.AddRange(vCPUs);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        return objectCount;
                    }
                    int VmId = vInfo.GetID(dr["VM"].ToString(), dr["Host"].ToString(), dr["Datacenter"].ToString(), dr["Cluster"].ToString(), assessment_id);
                    int? Amount = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("CPUs") && dr["CPUs"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["CPUs"]) : (int?)null; //Amount is NumCPUs
                    int? Sockets = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Sockets") && dr["Sockets"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sockets"]) : (int?)null;
                    int? CoresPerSocket = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Cores p/s") && dr["Cores p/s"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cores p/s"]) : (int?)null;
                    int? Max = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Max") && dr["Max"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Max"]) : (int?)null;
                    int? Overall = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Overall") && dr["Overall"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Overall"]) : (int?)null; 
                    string Level = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Level") && dr["Level"] != DBNull.Value) ? dr["Level"].ToString() : "";
                    int? Shares = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Shares") && dr["Shares"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Shares"]) : (int?)null; 
                    int? Reservation = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Reservation") && dr["Reservation"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Reservation"]) : (int?)null; 
                    int? Entitlement = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Entitlement") && dr["Entitlement"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Entitlement"]) : (int?)null; 
                    int? DrsEntitlement = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("DRS Entitlement") && dr["DRS Entitlement"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["DRS Entitlement"]) : (int?)null;
                    int? Limit = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Limit") && dr["Limit"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(dr["Limit"]) : (int?)null; 
                    bool? HotAdd = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Hot Add") && dr["Hot Add"] != DBNull.Value) ? bool.Parse(dr["Hot Add"].ToString()) : (bool?)null; 
                    bool? HotRemove = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Hot Remove") && dr["Hot Remove"] != DBNull.Value) ? bool.Parse(dr["Hot Remove"].ToString()) : (bool?)null;
                    string Annotation = (dr.Table.Columns.Contains("Annotation") && dr["Annotation"] != DBNull.Value) ? dr["Annotation"].ToString() : "";

                    vCPUs.Add(new RvtoolsVCpu()
                    {
                        VmId = VmId, //Get VM_ID
                        Amount = Amount,
                        Sockets = Sockets,
                        CoresPerSocket = CoresPerSocket,
                        Max = Max,
                        Overall = Overall,
                        Level = Level,
                        Shares = Shares,
                        Reservation = Reservation,
                        Entitlement = Entitlement,
                        DrsEntitlement = DrsEntitlement,
                        Limit = Limit,
                        HotAdd = HotAdd,
                        HotRemove = HotRemove,
                        Annotation = Annotation,
                        AssessmentId = assessment_id
                    });
                    objectCount += 16;
                }
                context.RvtoolsVCpu.AddRange(vCPUs);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return objectCount;
            }
        }
    }
```

This vCPU class is rather small compared to some of the other Excel Sheets that have to be imported... you might be able to see now why I'm searching for optimization.

Within the `foreach` loop, you can ignore the `vInfo.GetID( ... );` since that is already optimized. Looking at the objects within each row, however, is where things get bulky. Here's why I have what I have in there, but any suggestions for better solutions would be greatly appreciated:

1. `dr.Table.Columns.Contains("CPUs")` -- This is used since there are different versions of these Excel files. Some of them don't have the same columns, so when `ExcelDataReader` tries to access a column that isn't there, the program breaks and the import fails.
2. `dr["CPUs"] != DBNull.Value` -- This is used since sometimes there is nothing in a specific Excel cell, and that tends to run into an error when you try to convert nothing to an integer.

Thus, if both of these conditionals return true, the data cell is converted to the correct object type. Otherwise, it is converted to the null value of that object type. This works really great for avoiding errors! Unfortunately, it doesn't allow the program to chug along fast.

After each object in a row is either converted or set to null, `Entity Framework Core` comes into play. The `List<vCPUs>` object keeps gaining objects until the end of the Excel Sheet has been reached. All of the data is then pushed to a SQL Server Database and the program moves onto the next Excel Sheet.

Where can I improve on this program?

Comment: Use data readers from excel files to feed SqlBulkInsert. It is the most effient way to load data into SQL Server using .NET.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Is there a link you can send for this? The only implementation I can find is through using SQL language and this needs to work within ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Sorry it is SqlBulkCopy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 it is available in .net core and .net framwork as well.

Comment: @JesúsLópez This is a great solution for me! There is one issue however. In my post I said to ignore the ```vInfo.GetID( ... );``` but with using this I would have to have the program set these ID's since that is not copying data. Any thoughts on how I could do that? Maybe you could post some solution?

Comment: You probably want an identity column for the IDs. Any column you don't map to `SqlBulkCopy` will use the default for that column

Comment: @Pecker. Id can be seen as a calculated field, right? Perhaps you could use the decorator pattern to implement a data reader that adds some calculated fields to another data reader. Another option is filling a data table from excel data reader, then add the id column to the data table and set its value for each row, and finally feed SqlBulkCopy with the data table. SqlBulkCopy can accept a data table as well. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_DataTable_